# Android emulator visuals looks large (abnormal)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am using eclipse for android development in Windows 7. I created a new emulator for testing my app. The emulator UI is totally looks zoomed and i can't view my testing app in emulator.

App is successfully running in emulator but UI is totally zoomed and i can't select or click any option. Below is the screen of the emulator.

[image]

I tried reset the emulator and the problem is not solved.

Can any one know how to make reset the zoomed feature of my emulator to normal.

Comment: Check the screen dimensions in avd definition

Comment: For the record, this appears to be a bug in Android SDK Tools 24.4 - it's also happened to all my AVDs.

Comment: Having same problem after updating to 24.4... Still looking for solutions as well

Comment: @GregEllis have you found any solution.

Comment: @user2681579 I ended up re-creating my AVD devices using the clone... method. Some of the devices I tried to clone worked normally and some still ended up being scaled or zoomed up. So just through trial and error I managed to get a small device, medium size device, and small device created. I don't know why some work and some don't though... I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the AVD, click on the drop down next to the emulator.

Look for the section that says: "Startup size and orientation"

Change the scale there. The top item (at least on mine) is "10dp on device = 1px on screen" which will give you the smallest view. Play around with this setting.

*If you continue to have issues, you might consider recreating the emulator device.*

Comment: Do you mean in the AVD manager? Only I don't have a dropdown - I just have an "Edit..." button and although that option looks like exactly what I want, it doesn't appear anywhere in there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by going into the "Device Definitions" tab of the AVD manager, cloning an existing AVD and changing the "Density" to be something else (in my case it worked selecting "nodpi"). You then have to change your AVD to use that device definition.